# ¿Cómo obtener el error incluido en BadRequest?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

En el server tengo:

```
string errorMessage = string.Format("Error: the following employeee has an invalid department: {0} {1}", new[] { employeeWithMissingDepartment.Id.ToString(), employeeWithMissingDepartment.Name });

return BadRequest(errorMessage);
```

Como puedes ver estoy mandando la descripción del error en el método `BadRequest`.

En el cliente hago lo siguiente:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = this.PostAsJsonAsync<T>("api/controller/action", parameter).Result;

if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                error= response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
```

En este caso la variable error solo obtiene "BadRequest" y no el descriptivo mensaje de error que yo formé, **¿cómo obtengo el mensaje de error en `BadRequest`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambos response (respuestas HTTP OK y BadRequest) envian el mensaje en manera diferente. SI bien ambos envian en el cuerpo del Mensaje

**TEMA 1: Reason Phrase (HTTP)**

Antes que nada una aclaracion sobre **[ReasonPhrase](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1)** que es la descripción (en inglés) del comando http... simplemente para hacerlo mas "humano" al codigo. Ejemplos

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

**TEMA 2: ¿Mensaje de respuesta en WebAPI con Response OK & BadRequest?**

Miremos por ejemplo una response OK donde envía el mensaje. [En la propiedad Content del response (la respuesta es del tipo OkNegotiatedContentResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt175429.aspx)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SI vemos [la respuesta para un response BadRequest (del tipo BadRequestErrorMessageResult) vemos que la propiedad que se setea es Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.http.results.badrequesterrormessageresult.message(v=vs.118).aspx)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vemos mas arriba entonces, ambos soportan envio de "mensajes" pero son dos propiedades diferentes. Si vas a utilizar BAdRequest necesitas saber esto.

**TEMA 3: ¿Como serializa (como es la respuesta)?**

Y como leer dicha respuesta! Bueno el OK devuelve en el contenido del response (texto plano). Pero BadRequest serializa a un objeto que tiene un propiedad Message
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces deberías tener esto en cuenta para obtener el mensaje

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Enlaces que te pueden servir

- HTTP 1.1 : Response > Status Code and Reason Phrase https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1
- [OK. Clase OkNegotiatedContentResult. Propiedad Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt175429.aspx)
- [BadRequest. Clase BadRequestErrorMessageResult. Propiedad Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.http.results.badrequesterrormessageresult.message(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente se obtiene asi:

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            error= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

Es lo mismo que cuando regresas un Ok 200.